# How to convert site from using URL-based Session Tracking to Cookied-based Session Tracking in PHP?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I've inherited a site that uses URL-based Session Tracking.

Here is the session settings via phpinfo():

[image: phpinfo session settings]

Here is the code used on every page of the script to initiate Sessions:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.name', 'ID');
ini_set('arg_separator.output', '&amp;');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1440);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 30);
session_start();
```

PHP seems to automatically append `&SID=[sessionid]` to any internal link on the site.  Furthermore, throughout the PHP script, there are internal URL's manually appended with `.'&amp;ID='.session_id()`.

I assume the previous developer did things this way in order for the site to work on cellphones with no cookies.

In 2011, that doesn't seem to be an issue anymore as almost all cellphones on the market accept cookies. **So how can I convert the site back to handling sessions the default way via cookies (specifically, what files would I need to change and how)?**

**Also, is it possible to have the site handle sessions differently depending on whether the user accepts cookies or not?  If so, then how?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like php.ini has the correct setting for use_cookies, so you could remove the first line to enable that, or change it to 1. Looking at the [session configuration options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php), it doesn't look like there's a way to automatically use the URL-based session ID if the browser isn't accepting cookies.

Comment: I tried setting session.use_cookies to '1' and it's still using the URL-based Sessions and automatically appending the Session ID to the URL.  Any other ideas?

Comment: The fact that phpinfo() is seeing certain values makes me think there's an .htaccess somewhere that has these parameters, or some other kind of local config file overriding php.ini. Could you look for something like that?

Answer (score 0):

change in your php.ini (or with `ini_set`) value for  `session.use_only_cookies` to `on`, that should stop PHP from adding SID to urls

Of course you will also need to get rid of every `ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);` an manually appended `session_id()`

Comment: If session.use_only_cookies is set to off, is it possible to use both session types, and that way also offer compatibility with old cellphones that don't work with cookies?